# How to resolve issue with moduleResolution property of tsconfig.json file in VSCode

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I have created a Next JS app and have opened that in the VS code.
Then I opened the tsconfig.json file and found that it is having an issue related to the moduleResolution property.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Error on line 1,

```
[ts] Argument for '--moduleResolution' option must be: 'node', 'classic'.
```

Need help to figure out what's wrong in this json.
[image: Error_SS]

I have tried changing the module to NodeNext but it is not working...

Comment: Was because of the old vs code version. Updated the vs code and was resolved.